# Why the command rightmargin=5cm, and leftmargin=5cm, in {mdframed}‎‎ package not work in book style?

Tags: mdframed

I want create frame with custom left and right margin in book style with this command:(When I use article style the output is good)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}‎
% ‎‎ ‎‎\documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{book}‎
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}‎
‎\usepackage{mdframed}‎‎
‎\usepackage{color}‎‎
‎‎\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt‎,
‎skipbelow=7pt‎,
‎rightline=true‎,
‎leftline=true‎,
‎topline=true‎,
‎bottomline=true‎,
‎backgroundcolor=blue!15‎,
‎linecolor=black!5‎,
‎innerleftmargin=5pt‎,
‎innerrightmargin=5pt‎,
‎innertopmargin=5pt‎,
‎roundcorner=5mm‎,
‎innerbottommargin=5pt‎,
‎linewidth=4pt‎,‎
rightmargin=5cm,leftmargin=5cm,
]{margbox}‎
\begin{document}‎
‎\begin{margbox}‎
som tex som tex som tex som tex som tex som tex som tex som tex ‎
som tex som tex som tex som tex som tex som tex 
\end{margbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that I use asymmetric margins in my examples to show the difference between them.

As default `rightmargin` and `leftmargin` are keys for the oneside mode. If you have a twosided document you normally want to use `innermargin` and `outermargin`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
  innermargin=.5cm,
  outermargin=3cm,
]{margbox}

\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{margbox}‎
\lipsum[1]
\end{margbox}
\clearpage
\begin{margbox}‎
\lipsum[1]
\end{margbox}
\clearpage
\begin{margbox}‎
\lipsum[1]
\end{margbox}
\end{document}
```

Run twice to get the margins right:

[image]

If you really want to set the right and left margins also in twoside mode add `usetwoside=false` to your options:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
  leftmargin=.5cm,
  rightmargin=3cm,
  usetwoside=false
]{margbox}

\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{margbox}‎
\lipsum[1]
\end{margbox}
\clearpage
\begin{margbox}‎
\lipsum[1]
\end{margbox}
\clearpage
\begin{margbox}‎
\lipsum[1]
\end{margbox}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]